# Can Web sphere Liberty manage multiple JTA sources?

Tags: jpa, websphere-liberty

when I add more that one jta-data-source in persistence.xml i run into a runtime exception

```
[ERROR   ] CWWJP0012E: The persistence unit name is not specified and a unique persistence unit is not found in the CoplinkRestService application and CoplinkRestService.war module.
[ERROR   ] CWWJP0029E: The server cannot find the  persistence unit in the CoplinkRestService.war module and the CoplinkRestService application.
[ERROR   ] CWNEN0035E: The java:comp/env/CLDB reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the null component in the CoplinkRestService.war module of the CoplinkRestService application cannot be resolved.
[ERROR   ] CNTR0019E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "getPersonDetails". Exception data: javax.ejb.EJBException: The java:comp/env/CLDB reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the null component in the CoplinkRestService.war module of the CoplinkRestService application cannot be resolved.
    at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionBinding.getInjectionObject(InjectionBinding.java:1494)
    at [internal classes]
    at com.ibm.coplink.enterprise.details.person.EJSLocalNSLPersonDetailsEJB_df3bc29f.getPersonDetails(EJSLocalNSLPersonDetailsEJB_df3bc29f.java)
    at com.ibm.coplink.enterprise.details.DetailsHandlerEJB$$Lambda$8.000000001A297440.apply(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.coplink.enterprise.details.DetailsHandlerEJB.getDetails(DetailsHandlerEJB.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:495)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.invokeProceed(EJSContainer.java:5323)
    at [internal classes]
    at com.ibm.coplink.enterprise.details.EJSLocalNSLDetailsHandlerEJB_c56b7144.getDetails(EJSLocalNSLDetailsHandlerEJB_c56b7144.java)
    at com.ibm.coplink.service.CoplinkRestServiceImpl.deleteMe(CoplinkRestServiceImpl.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:495)
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.server.LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.performInvocation(LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.java:607)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] CNTR0020E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "getDetails" on bean "BeanId(CoplinkRestService#CoplinkRestService.war#DetailsHandlerEJB, null)". Exception data: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: nested exception is: javax.ejb.EJBException: The java:comp/env/CLDB reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the null component in the CoplinkRestService.war module of the CoplinkRestService application cannot be resolved.
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.BusinessExceptionMappingStrategy.mapCSIException(BusinessExceptionMappingStrategy.java:127)
    at [internal classes]
    at com.ibm.coplink.enterprise.details.person.EJSLocalNSLPersonDetailsEJB_df3bc29f.getPersonDetails(EJSLocalNSLPersonDetailsEJB_df3bc29f.java)
    at com.ibm.coplink.enterprise.details.DetailsHandlerEJB$$Lambda$8.000000001A297440.apply(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.coplink.enterprise.details.DetailsHandlerEJB.getDetails(DetailsHandlerEJB.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:495)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.invokeProceed(EJSContainer.java:5323)
    at [internal classes]
    at com.ibm.coplink.enterprise.details.EJSLocalNSLDetailsHandlerEJB_c56b7144.getDetails(EJSLocalNSLDetailsHandlerEJB_c56b7144.java)
    at com.ibm.coplink.service.CoplinkRestServiceImpl.deleteMe(CoplinkRestServiceImpl.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:495)
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.server.LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.performInvocation(LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.java:607)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: The java:comp/env/CLDB reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the null component in the CoplinkRestService.war module of the CoplinkRestService application cannot be resolved.
    at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionBinding.getInjectionObject(InjectionBinding.java:1494)
    ... 18 more

[WARNING ] Application {http://service.coplink.ibm.com/}CoplinkRestServiceImpl has thrown exception, unwinding now
nested exception is: javax.ejb.EJBException: The java:comp/env/CLDB reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the null component in the CoplinkRestService.war module of the CoplinkRestService application cannot be resolved.
[WARNING ] Exception in handleFault on interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSDefaultFaultOutInterceptor@8ca66b2
nested exception is: javax.ejb.EJBException: The java:comp/env/CLDB reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the null component in the CoplinkRestService.war module of the CoplinkRestService application cannot be resolved.
[ERROR   ] Error occurred during error handling, give up!
nested exception is: javax.ejb.EJBException: The java:comp/env/CLDB reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the null component in the CoplinkRestService.war module of the CoplinkRestService application cannot be resolved.
[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage:116'
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: nested exception is: javax.ejb.EJBException: The java:comp/env/CLDB reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the null component in the CoplinkRestService.war module of the CoplinkRestService application cannot be resolved.
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:116)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: nested exception is: javax.ejb.EJBException: The java:comp/env/CLDB reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the null component in the CoplinkRestService.war module of the CoplinkRestService application cannot be resolved.
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:163)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: nested exception is: javax.ejb.EJBException: The java:comp/env/CLDB reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the null component in the CoplinkRestService.war module of the CoplinkRestService application cannot be resolved.
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.BusinessExceptionMappingStrategy.mapCSIException(BusinessExceptionMappingStrategy.java:127)
    at [internal classes]
    at com.ibm.coplink.enterprise.details.person.EJSLocalNSLPersonDetailsEJB_df3bc29f.getPersonDetails(EJSLocalNSLPersonDetailsEJB_df3bc29f.java)
    at com.ibm.coplink.enterprise.details.DetailsHandlerEJB$$Lambda$8.000000001A297440.apply(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.coplink.enterprise.details.DetailsHandlerEJB.getDetails(DetailsHandlerEJB.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:495)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.invokeProceed(EJSContainer.java:5323)
    at [internal classes]
    at com.ibm.coplink.enterprise.details.EJSLocalNSLDetailsHandlerEJB_c56b7144.getDetails(EJSLocalNSLDetailsHandlerEJB_c56b7144.java)
    at com.ibm.coplink.service.CoplinkRestServiceImpl.deleteMe(CoplinkRestServiceImpl.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:495)
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.server.LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.performInvocation(LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.java:607)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: The java:comp/env/CLDB reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the null component in the CoplinkRestService.war module of the CoplinkRestService application cannot be resolved.
    at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionBinding.getInjectionObject(InjectionBinding.java:1494)
    ... 18 more
```

my persistence.xml entries :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="CLDB">
        <jta-data-source>coplink-database</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
           <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL"/>
           <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    <persistence-unit name="CL_ADMIN">
        <jta-data-source>coplink-admin-database</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
           <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL"/>
           <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

my server.xml entries :

```
<dataSource id="coplink-database" jndiName="coplink-database" statementCacheSize="20" type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource">
    <properties.microsoft.sqlserver databaseName="Coplink_DemoCLDB_4.8.1.0" password="cldb_password" portNumber="1433" user="cldb_user"/>
    <connectionManager agedTimeout="-1" connectionTimeout="30s" maxIdleTime="30m" maxPoolSize="100" minPoolSize="10" reapTime="15m"/>
    <jdbcDriver>
        <library description="SQLServerDriver" name="SQLServerDriver">
            <!-- Relative path to JDBC Driver.  Eg. wlp/usr/servers/COPLINKSearchAPIandUI/resources/sqljdbc41.jar -->
            <file name="resources/sqljdbc41.jar"/>
        </library>
    </jdbcDriver>
</dataSource>

<dataSource id="coplink-admin-database" jndiName="coplink-admin-database" statementCacheSize="20" type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource">
    <properties.microsoft.sqlserver databaseName="Coplink_DemoAdmin_4.8.1.0" password="cldb_password" portNumber="1433" user="cldb_user"/>
    <connectionManager agedTimeout="-1" connectionTimeout="30s" maxIdleTime="30m" maxPoolSize="100" minPoolSize="10" reapTime="15m"/>
    <jdbcDriver>
        <library description="SQLServerDriver" name="SQLServerDriver">
            <!-- Relative path to JDBC Driver.  Eg. wlp/usr/servers/COPLINKSearchAPIandUI/resources/sqljdbc41.jar -->
            <file name="resources/sqljdbc41.jar"/>
        </library>
    </jdbcDriver>
</dataSource>
```

my java reference :

```
@PersistenceContext(name = "CLDB")
private EntityManager cldbManager;
```

Comment: <persistence-unit name="CLDB">
  <jta-data-source>coplink-database</jta-data-source>
  <properties>
           <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL"/>
           <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
        </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
 <persistence-unit name="CL_ADMIN">
  <jta-data-source>coplink-admin-database</jta-data-source>
  <properties>
           <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL"/>
           <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
        </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `@PersistenceContext(unitName="CLDB")`.  The `name` is only used to control the `java:comp/env/` name.  The `unitName` is optional until you have a second `<persistence-unit>`, and then you need to specify which unit you want.

(The `CWWJP0029E` message seems like poor serviceability since it shows `the  persistence unit` with two spaces, so it actually means `the "" persistence unit`.  This should probably be reported to IBM to either fix or remove this error message in this case.)

Comment: is correct in his observation about the error message printing the empty unitName string.  No need to report this to IBM, they have taken note of it and it will be corrected in the future.

Comment: @aguibert Thanks :-).

Comment: @user2397334 If the answer solved your problem, you should click the checkmark to the left of the answer to accept it.  This increases my reputation and improves your acceptance rate so that others are more likely to answer your questions in the future.